# Azure SQL Database Private Endpoint DNS and AD/AAD Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network, connectivity

We have an Azure Express Route that allows us to extend our on-prem network into Azure vNets.  Within one of the vNets/subnet, I have created a private endpoint and associated it to an Azure SQL Database.  I configured this within the Azure SQL DB blade.

From my laptop (across VPN into the corp net), I'm able to connect to the Azure SQL DB using the private IP + SQL Authentication (using the SQL DB server name @).

I'm also able to connect using **AAD Universal with MFA** to the public fqdn/IP.  Love this.

I want to be able to connect using the private IP (using a name) AND AAD Universal w MFA (or even just AAD w Password).

We tried adding a DNS entry to our custom/on-prem AD DNS (an A Record with a custom name - not the fqdn as provided by Azure) that resolves to the private endpoint IP just fine.  However, when we attempt to connect using anything but SQL Auth, we get:

"target principal name is incorrect"

[image: SSMS Connection Error Message]

How can we configure this correctly to allow users to connect via name/fqdn with AAD Universal w MFA?

TIA,
-Pete

Answer (score 0):

can you try to tick the option in SMSS to "Trust Server Certificate in the SMSS connection settings"

Regards,

Comment: Thank you, @alphaz18.  I received that possibility from a bud at MS, too.  It definitely works!  He also said that he doesn't recommend using that as "the solution".  Seems like he's steering towards the DNS forwarding architecture suggested in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns#virtual-network-and-on-premises-workloads-using-a-dns-forwarder

Comment: He also suggested a second, less desirable option: to use custom DNS (on-prem AD), but to still use the same fqdn as the azure SQL DB <DBName>.database.windows.net.

Comment: Great that you found that. and yes Microsoft always wants to steer you to use their DNS naming for sql infrastructure. though I know many organizations and people who don't like that, they prefer their own ip and their own fqdns. Really up to you how you want to do it, as you have 3 options there. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the regular dns (host.database.windows.net) for the sql server, no the one that resolves to the private link (host.privatelink.database.windows.net)

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/azure-sql-db-private-link-private-endpoint-connectivity/ba-p/1235573